Peeking at the result of a Doobie query using fs2 to materialize errors
I want to stream the result of a Doobie query as JSON using htpp4s. The core problem is that errors (like malformed query) are only occuring during stream evaluation when http4s has already sent the header (status Ok) and begins to stream the body.
Thus, I tried to create a function peekFirstElement, which shall materialize an error that happens during fetching the first chunk into the enclosing IO.
I've hit a dead end, as the current implementation fails after streaming the first chunk with an exception from Postgres that the result set has already been closed.
If there is only one chunk, next() that delivers the last item of the first chunk signals end of result set. But somehow my the code tries to pull another chunk from the closed set.
In cases where there are multiple chunks, close is apparently called by doobie after peeking at the first chunk. So my code also fails after the first chunk, but in a different way.
If I do not use the peekFirstElement function, I can stream the result successfully.
Any thoughts?
Edit
When changing chunk size on the Doobie stream to only 2, I also only get the first chunk as output before the error that the result set is closed. In this case close of the PgResultSet is called by Doobie somehow.
Code
  /** Peeks at first element of stream to materialize any exceptions that might occur. */
  def peekFirstElement[O](stream: Stream[IO, O]): IO[Stream[IO, O]] = {
    val x: Pull[IO, Stream[IO, O], Unit] = stream.pull.uncons.flatMap {
      case Some((first, tl)) =>
        Pull.output1(Stream.chunk(first) ++ tl)
      case None =>
        Pull.output1(Stream.empty)
    }
    x.stream.compile.onlyOrError
  }

  def routes(conns: List[(Regex, Transactor[IO])]): HttpRoutes[IO] = {
    val config = FileService.Config[IO](absolutePath)
    //post process the file content by interpreting it as a query and executing it
    val pathCollector: FileService.Fs2PathCollector[IO] = (f, cfg, request) => {
      conns.find(_._1.matches(request.pathInfo.toString))
        .map { case (_, transactor) =>
          for {
            content <- config.fs2PathCollector(f, cfg, request)
            query <- OptionT.liftF(content.body.compile.toList.map(bytes => new String(bytes.toArray)))
            _ <- OptionT.liftF(logger[IO].debug(s"executing query: \"$query\""))
            outerQuery = sql"select to_json(querydata) from (${Fragment.const(query)}) as querydata".query[Json]
            queryResult = outerQuery.stream.transact(transactor)
            queryPeeked <- OptionT.liftF(peekFirstElement(queryResult))
            streamList = Stream.emit(Token.StartArray) ++ queryPeeked.through(tokenize) ++ Stream(Token.EndArray)
            response <- OptionT.liftF(
              Ok(streamList.through(fs2.data.json.render.compact).through(fs2.text.utf8.encode)).handleErrorWith(
                e => InternalServerError(e.toString)
              )
            )
          } yield response
        }.getOrElse(config.fs2PathCollector(f, cfg, request))
    }

    fileService[IO](FileService.Config[IO](absolutePath, pathCollector, "", NoopCacheStrategy[IO], 32 * 1024))
  }


I was able to reproduce locally with Postgres without an htt4s part.
I believe the issue is that fs2.Stream handles a resource scope under the hood and closes the reading of ResultSet when an underlying Pull is complete so it's unsafe to work with an underlying pull.
Splitting the queryResult into queryResult.head and queryResult.tail, and then explicitly reading the head before returning a response can fix the issue. I've checked and it worked for me. So consider adjusting the corresponding lines with the snippet below:
            headOpt <- OptionT.liftF(queryResult.head.compile.last) // evaluate head
            queryPeeked = Stream.fromOption(headOpt) ++ queryResult.tail


I have the feeling that this will result in two queries to the DB.

I also think the problem is that fs2 runs the clean-up code. Maybe this is understandable, as there is no guarantee that the tail stream from peek will get run after looking at the peeked element. But it's also pretty useless that way.
